# How can i host an Apple enterprise app download page on Sharepoint

Tags: ios, sharepoint, app-distribution

I am trying to find a way to host my enterprise distributed apps on our company Sharepoint site. I created a site and uploaded the .plist and the .ipa files to the site's "documents", linking them with the `<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=[link to plist]`-command but i does not seem to work, tapping the link on the iOS device nothing happens. Is there a workable strategy hosting both the app installations files and the download link on Sharepoint.

Comment: I don't think you want `&amp;` in the url. You just want `&`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Several community articles mention that the root-cause of this issue is an authentication layer; if we consider this to be a root-cause, the entire SharePoint (OnPremises or Online) or any web site that contains an authentication provider will prevent the proper consumption of these files; BUT, I don't think it's the real problem, because the file extensions mentioned in your question are not supported by MIME types in SharePoint. Please, if possible, inspect the link with Browser Developer Tools and verify that the HTML of the link is rendered correctly; unfortunately, there is not much hope in solving this problem natively. You may try to develop some custom App for SharePoint using [SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) or [SharePoint Add-In Hosted App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins) to try to solve this issue, but you will have a hard work to do